# Benchmark Hadoop using TestDFSIO

Tags: performance, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to the Hadoop, I am using TestDFSIO for performance of the cluster.

What make me confuse that performance test should be run before or after implementing the HDFS ?

It my first post here. If I am wrong somewhere please ignore.

Comment: The question isn't clear. What original file are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Original file means file on which we implement the mapreduce.